# Trying to solve Newtonian polytopes with Solve_ivp and the correctness varies for different values of n?

Tags: python, scipy, solver

I'm trying to solve the newtonian stellar structure equations for polytropic equations of state (I'm solving polytropes).  I'm not using the Lane-Emden equations.  This should be a very straightforward code as it's a simple linear system of two equations. The equation of state is also simple.

Since stack overflow doesn't accept tex and it won't let me imbed an image. I'm not sure how to put the newtonian equations here in a neat way, so here is the best I can manage:

dm/dr = 4 pi rho r^2

dp/dr = - G rho M / r^2

For n=1 there's an exact solution of the polytrope and my pressure-radius curve matches exactly and the numerical radius is within 0.0003 percent error of the exact solution radius.

However, for n=3, I'm getting a mass of 1.43 solar masses instead of 1.24.

For n=3/2, all of my calculated radii are 3.7x the published version and the masses are 28x the published results.  I'm not sure what's causing this.

I've done the code in geometric units with dimensionless quantities and with everything in SI and the results I get are consistent.  Which tells me that its not from errors from dealing with large numbers.  So I'll put the SI code here so that things aren't confused by change of units and scaling factors.

The code for the polytope calculation is this:

```
#for gamma = 4/3

K = ((hbar * c) /(12*np.pi**2.)) * ((3*np.pi**2.)/(m_h))**(4./3.)  
K = K * 0.5**(4./3.)


#for gamma = 5/3 

K_nr = hbar_cgs**2.
K_nr = K_nr /(15. *np.pi**2. * me_cgs) 
K_nr = K_nr * (3. * np.pi**2. )**(5./3.)
K_nr = K_nr * (mh_cgs)**(-5./3.)
K_nr = K_nr * 0.5**(5./3.)

#Equation of State

def EOS(p):

    rho = (p/K)**(1./gamma)

    return rho


def TOV(r,y):
    M = y[0]
    p = y[1]

    rho = EOS(p)
    #print p
    dMdr = 4. * np.pi * rho * r**2.
    dpdr = - G * M * rho /r**2.
    #print dpdr


    return [dMdr,dpdr]

def star_boundary(r,y):
    return y[1]

#Set star boundary at pressure = 0
star_boundary.terminal = True

M_0 = 0.
r_0 = 0.01 #m
r_stop = 20. #km
r_stop = r_stop * 10.**(3.) #SI = m
t_span = (r_0,r_stop)
t_eval = np.linspace(r_0,r_stop,1000)
p0 = 10**33.
y0 = [M_0, p0]

soln = solve_ivp(TOV,t_span,y0,method='RK45', events=star_boundary, t_eval=t_eval, dense_output=True)

r = soln.t
M = soln.y[0]
p = soln.y[1]
```

The code to calculate the exact solution is here:

```
rho0 = EOS(p0)
R = (((1.+1.)*p0 )/(4*np.pi * g_cgs * rho0**2))**0.5 * np.pi  
error = abs((r[-1] - R)/R)
print "percent error is ", error


R_s = (((1.+1.)*p0 )/(4*np.pi * g_cgs * rho0**2))**0.5
xi = r / R_s
theta = np.sin(xi) / xi
P = p0 * theta**(n+1)
```

I have checked my K value with 3 different papers.  I've checked that the output xi is equal to pi.  I need to find the error before I go on to the GR solution and I am quite stuck.

I also checked smaller values of r_0 (since you can't actually use r=0) and I found that the solution is stable around this point.)

I also tried lowering the rtol/atol on the integrator in case it was just accumulating error but changing rtol from the default rtol=10E-3 to 10E-6 did nothing.

I also checked with scipy.odeint

Answer (score 0):

Update:  It turns out there was an error in the publication I was comparing to.  It turns out that approx 1.43 is correct (it's related to th Chandrasekhar mass)